# rewrite engine setting

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

I can see the following entries in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

What is the use of these lines in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Enable the runtime rewriting engine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
```

If request method is `TRACE` or `TRACK`.

```
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Force URL to be forbidden. The dash (`-`) means that don't substitute.

Answer (score 1):

This group of directives forbids (returns a 403 response) all HTTP requests using the `TRACE` or `TRACK` methods.